STM32 debugger shows wrong stack pointer
Before explaining the problem I want to say as a disclaimer that I am a total beginner with baremetal coding in ARM, so the problem could be anywhere.
I am following this guide to move my first steps. The big difference with the guide is that I have a STM32H753ZI board. I modified the code of the example in the following way in order to adapt it to the different hardware:
STM32H753ZI.ld:
/* Define the end of RAM and limit of stack memory */
_estack = 0x3001FFFC;

MEMORY
{
    FLASH ( rx )    : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 1024K
    RAM ( rxw )     : ORIGIN = 0x30000000, LENGTH = 126K
}


core.S:
// These instructions define attirbutes of our chip and
// the assembly language we'll use
.syntax unified
.cpu cortex-m7
.fpu softvfp 
.thumb

// Global memory locations
.global vtable
.global reset_handler

/*
* The actual vector table.
* Only the size of RAM and 'reset' handler are
* included for simplicity
*/
.type vtable, %object
vtable:
    .word _estack
    .word reset_handler
.size vtable, .-vtable


/*  
* The Reset handler. Called on reset.  
*/ 
.type reset_handler, %function 
reset_handler:   
    // Set the stack pointer to the end of the stack.   
    // The '_estack' value is defined in our linker script.   
    LDR  r0, =_estack   
    MOV  sp, r0   
    // Set some dummy values. When we see these values   
    // in our debugger, we'll know that our program   
    // is loaded on the chip and working.   
    LDR  r7, =0xDEADBEEF   
    MOVS r0, #0   
    MOVS r1, #6   
    main_loop:     
        // Add 1 to register 'r0'.     
        ADDS r0, r0, #1     
        // Loop back.     
        B    main_loop 
    .size reset_handler, .-reset_handler

Then, I compile and link it with the following two commands:
arm-none-eabi-gcc -x assembler-with-cpp -c -O0 -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -Wall core.S -o core.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc core.o -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -Wall --specs=nosys.specs -nostdlib -lgcc -T./STM32H753ZI.ld -o main.elf

No compilation and linking error appears up to this point. If I try to deassemble the code with arm-none-eabi-objdump -zd core.o, this is what I get:
core.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <vtable>:
   0:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                             ........

00000008 <reset_handler>:
   8:   4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   @ (18 <main_loop+0x6>)
   a:   4685        mov sp, r0
   c:   4f03        ldr r7, [pc, #12]   @ (1c <main_loop+0xa>)
   e:   2000        movs    r0, #0
  10:   2106        movs    r1, #6

00000012 <main_loop>:
  12:   3001        adds    r0, #1
  14:   e7fd        b.n 12 <main_loop>
  16:   0000        .short  0x0000
  18:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
  1c:   deadbeef    .word   0xdeadbeef

So far everything seems okay. However, when I load the code on the STM32 with arm-none-eabi-gdb --eval-command="target extended-remote :4242" main.elf and investigate the register with info-register this is what I see:
(gdb) info register
r0             0x8                 8
r1             0x800040c           134218764
r2             0x0                 0
r3             0x4000              16384
r4             0x0                 0
r5             0x4                 4
r6             0x65                101
r7             0x0                 0
r8             0x0                 0
r9             0x0                 0
r10            0x0                 0
r11            0x0                 0
r12            0x1                 1
sp             0x24009058          0x24009058
lr             0xffffffe9          4294967273
pc             0x802a1fe           0x802a1fe
cpsr           0x1000003           16777219


The r0 register seems to be working as intended and, if I let the code run for some time, I can see its value changing. However, neither the r1 register nor the r7 register are reporting the values that were assigned in the core.S file. Additionally, also the value reported in the register sp (stack pointer) is showing problems: according to the code that I have written, it should report the value saved in _estack (which is 0x3001FFFF). Obviously this is not happening.
Do you have any idea why the values reported are not the expected ones?
Edit 1:
@the busybee sorry for the late response.
If I deassemble main.elf I obtain the following values:

main.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <vtable>:
 8000000:   fc ff 01 30 09 00 00 08                             ...0....

08000008 <reset_handler>:
 8000008:   4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   @ (8000018 <main_loop+0x6>)
 800000a:   4685        mov sp, r0
 800000c:   4f03        ldr r7, [pc, #12]   @ (800001c <main_loop+0xa>)
 800000e:   2000        movs    r0, #0
 8000010:   2106        movs    r1, #6

08000012 <main_loop>:
 8000012:   3001        adds    r0, #1
 8000014:   e7fd        b.n 8000012 <main_loop>
 8000016:   0000        .short  0x0000
 8000018:   3001fffc    .word   0x3001fffc
 800001c:   deadbeef    .word   0xdeadbeef

For what concerns the real values that I see, they are reported at the end of the question. I am loading the code via gdb and printing the resgister with info register. I obtain the following:
(gdb) info register
r0             0x8                 8
r1             0x800040c           134218764
r2             0x0                 0
r3             0x4000              16384
r4             0x0                 0
r5             0x4                 4
r6             0x65                101
r7             0x0                 0
r8             0x0                 0
r9             0x0                 0
r10            0x0                 0
r11            0x0                 0
r12            0x1                 1
sp             0x24009058          0x24009058
lr             0xffffffe9          4294967273
pc             0x802a1fe           0x802a1fe
cpsr           0x1000003           16777219


Should I try to print something else?

Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. Then come back and [edit] your question to clarify.

Please disassemble the linked executable "core.elf". The unlinked object file does not resolve addresses.

Also, please add the actual values you see.

Hi @thebusybee, I have edited the question because the answer was too long for the comment, hope you can help me!

That is the right way. You never "answer" comments in the comments. This is not a forum. A question needs to contain all information you provide.
